# String.format() and hex numbers in Java

Tags: java, string, formatting, hex, twos-complement

I'm trying to figure out why `String.format()` is behaving the way it does.

Context: Systems programming class, writing an assembler.

There is a 5 character hex field in the object file, which I am creating from a value.

Tried using: `String.format("%05X", decInt);`

This works as intended for positive numbers
(11 -> `0000B`)
However it fails for negative numbers
(-1 -> `FFFFFFFF` instead of `FFFFF`)

I suppose I could just take a substring of the last 5 characters, but I would still like to figure out why it behaves this way.

Comment: The problem is the `width` set by the format method, in this case 5, is the minimum width.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The width used in format is always a minimum width. In this case, instead of using sub string operations I would suggest:

```
  String.format("%05X", decInt & 0xFFFFF);
```

Answer (score 16):

Format width only works to create a *minimum* number of digits, and only has effect on leading zeroes.

Instead of substring, you could use a bit mask:

```
String.format("%05X", decInt & 0x0FFFFF)
```

By the way, `11` -> `0000B`, not `0000A` as claimed in your question.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now. Also went back and modified the A->B, cheers