# Using Java StringBuilder Formatter class

Tags: java, parsing, formatter

I'm learning how to use java's Formatter class. 
I'd like to convert a positive byte to a hexadecimal number, then parse it into a String **with two digits**.

My method would look something like this:

```
String toHexString(byte byteToConvert) {
        StringBuilder hexBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        hexBuilder.append(Integer.toHexString(byteToConvert));
        return hexBuilder.toString();
}
```

Is there a way to be able to format the String (or the StringBuilder) to get two digits?

```
System.out.println(toHexString(127)); // Would like it to output "7f"
System.out.println(toHexString(1)); // Would like it to output "01"
```

Comment: `StringBuilder` isn't a formatter

Comment: A quick google search presents [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610254/string-format-and-hex-numbers-in-java) and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258415/how-to-get-hex-value-from-integer-in-java) as possible options

Comment: Where are you trying to use the Formatter class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `StringBuilder` here. Simply using [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) would do the trick:

```
String toHexString(byte byteToConvert) {
    return String.format("%02x", byteToConvert);
}
```